# Is it possible to browse through functions with Pycharm in Python like in Eclipse with Java?

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to browse through some objects which I instantiated, but they are not showing any methods. In Eclipse with Java I was used to browse the way is shown the screenshot:

[image]

Is this no longer possible because the **type** is only known at runtime in Python? What is the best way to see which methods the entry has.

Comment: well usually yes that depends on pycharm auto-infering types. In this case it might be that it can't infere the `feedparser` returned type. Look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html) about type hinting in pycharm which will help with the auto-completion. For example, on Python3 you could do `NewsFeed: <its type> = feedparser...` and then you will probably see the methods

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-F12? Also, maybe this may be of help? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206346879-Want-to-view-all-the-methods-available-in-a-given-Interface-or-Class

Comment: Do you want to view the project structure (`alt 7`)?

Comment: I have tried type hinting and CTRL + F12. Both did not get a better result.